# GSON fromJSON Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: kotlin, gson

I am trying to convert a string to JSONArray but I am having issues.

This is my test:

```
class MainActivityTest {

    @Test
    fun checkParse(){
        val loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
        val json: String = Files.lines(
            get(
                loader.getResource("data.json").toURI()
            )
        )
            .parallel()
            .collect(Collectors.joining())
        val main = MainActivity()
        val dataParse2 = Gson().fromJson(json, JSONArray::class.java)
        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
        val parse2 = gson.fromJson(json, Array<QuoteModel>::class.java).toList()
        val parse1 = main.parseResponse(dataParse2)

        assertEquals(parse1,parse2)
    }


}
```

This is the function I am testing in my MainActivity:

```
fun parseResponse(response: JSONArray): List<QuoteModel> {
    val fileData = response.toString()
    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
    return gson.fromJson(fileData, Array<QuoteModel>::class.java).toList()
}
```

And this is my data.json file:

```
[
  {
    "text": "Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration.",
    "author": "Thomas Edison"
  },
  {
    "text": "You can observe a lot just by watching.",
    "author": "Yogi Berra"
  },
  {
    "text": "A house divided against itself cannot stand.",
    "author": "Abraham Lincoln"
  }
]
```

the issue comes in this line from my test:

**val dataParse2 = Gson().fromJson(json, JSONArray::class.java)**

Any ideas?

---

**First Update**

This is the function where I call the parseFunction in MainActivity:

```
private fun jsonArrayRequest(url: String): JsonArrayRequest {
    return JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        { response ->

            val quotesArray = parseResponse(response)
            displayQuote(chooseQuote(quotesArray))
        },
        { error ->
            TODO("Handle error missing")
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun jsonArrayRequest(url: String): JsonArrayRequest {
return JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        { response ->

            val responseArray = JSONArray(response)
            val quotesArray = parseResponse(responseArray)
            displayQuote(chooseQuote(quotesArray))
        },
        { error ->
            TODO("Handle error missing")
        }
)

fun parseResponse(response: JSONArray): List<QuoteModel> {
return Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), Array<QuoteModel>::class.java).toList()
```

Comment: when I try to do that I got this message: Type mismatch.
Required:JSONArray, Found: JsonArray! . In the line: val parse1 = main.parseResponse(dataParse2)

Comment: dataParse2 in red there

Comment: use the same type in parseResponse method :

parseResponse(response: JsonArray)

Comment: I added information to the main question showing another function, so I can not do that because I am handling the response of a request. If I do that, I got an issue in the line:" val quotesArray = parseResponse(response) ". The only difference upside down, now it would be waiting for JsonArray and response is givin JASONArray

Comment: Thank you, Im fighting very hard with this one